# Not able to update react components inclusive if related state that is a map is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maps, state

In react I have the next state definition that will define which columns in my table will be hidden:

```
this.state = {
               colsHiddenStatus: new Map([['rowNumber',true], ['id', false], ['firstName', false], ['lastName', false], ['mobile', false], ['username', false], ['password', false]])   
        };
```

For example, in this case:

```
 column  'rowNumber'  will be hidden because ['rowNumber',true]
 column  'mobile'     will appear because ['mobile', false]
```

After running the next function:

```
handleSelectChange (value) {

    var xmap = this.state.colsHiddenStatus;
    console.log('==============' + xmap)

    for (var [key, val] of xmap)
    {
        console.log('>>>>======'+ fromSelObjectsToString(value));
        if  (fromSelObjectsToString(value).indexOf(key) >= 0)
        {
            console.log('key='+ key + '    val=true');
            xmap.set(key, false);               
        }
        else
        {
            xmap.set(key, true);
        }

    }   

    console.log('You\'ve selected: ');
    console.log('@@@@@@@@@@!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!' + value);
    this.setState({sel_valueArray: value });
    this.setState({colsHiddenStatus: xmap});

    // 'check loop'
    for (var [key, val] of this.state.colsHiddenStatus)
    {

        console.log('<<<<<<' + key + '======'+ this.state.colsHiddenStatus.get(key));


    }
}
```

Here: fromSelObjectsToString(value) returns a string like 'mobile;lastName' with some keys of colsHiddenStatus separated by semicolons. So, if a key of this map appears on this string then the respective column must be shown. For example, if fromSelObjectsToString(value) returns  'mobile;lastName'  then we will need to get ['mobile', false] at the  colsHiddenStatus map. Similar with lastName and all the others will need to be like: [key, true].

I know that  this.state.colsHiddenStatus   is being updated because the console always show the correct values at the 'check loop'. However, elements like:

```
<TableHeaderColumn key={"056"} dataField={'lastName'} hidden={this.state.colsHiddenStatus.get('lastName')}  </TableHeaderColumn>
```

aren't updated on the screen.

Additional Result: On console I saw for:

```
 >>>>======id;firstName;lastName;mobile;password
```

I obtained:

```
 <<<<<<id======false
 <<<<<<firstName======false
 <<<<<<lastName======false
 <<<<<<mobile======false
 <<<<<<username======true
 <<<<<<password======false
```

Any ideas why I have this problem?

Comment: not updated on screen means when handleSelectChange will get called, ui is not getting changed ?

Comment: yes... that's the case

Comment: expected result is: when `handleSelectChange` function get called only that column should appear on screen all other columns should be hidden ?

Comment: depends on the string returned by  fromSelObjectsToString(value). The string has some of the keys of colsHiddenStatus separated by  ;